# My keyboard shortcut for Canvas Size is broken

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, shortcuts

I'm on a Mac with Snow Leopard and it seems like there is some global keyboard shortcut overriding `Image > Canvas Size`. I'm guessing because in Safari the Console won't open either.
When i check in `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` I can't find the problem.

Is there another location for global shortcuts or is this problem caused by something else entirely?

Comment: The Canvas Size dialogue still opens from the menu, correct? Have you tried changing the shortcut to something else? And how does the Safari Console relate to this problem?

Comment: it's also `⌘+⌥+C` to open console in safari. creating a new shortcut works ok but i want to know where the problem is. that shortcut is used in many programs...

Comment: I thought that was the case but wasn't sure. Since it appears some other program is superceding your PS shortcut, this isn't really on-topic at GD.SE. I'm going to send it over to Super User for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different things you could try:

- Quit background applications like Alfred or Keyboard Maestro
- Check if the keys are shown as pressed in Keyboard Viewer (`/System/Library/Input Methods/KeyboardViewer.app`)
- Test if it works with other keyboards
- Test if it works on another account or a guest account